# Problems with POST request in java

Tags: java, post

I try to send a POST request programmatically in Java and get the following exception:

> "org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Forbidden"

However, if I use this form to send request in browser:

```
<form method=post action="http://gametest.phpnet.us">
    <p>Type : <input type=text name=request_type>
    <p>Name : <input type=text name=user_name>
    <p>Password : <input type=text name=user_password>
    <p><input type=submit name=send value=Send>
</form>
```

everything works fine (try with any Name and Password, Type must be "register", server must return xml "`<code>0</code>`").

Here is example of java code:

```
HttpParams defHttpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(defHttpParams, 5000);   
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(defHttpParams, 5000); 
String mServerUrl = "http://gametest.phpnet.us/index.php";
DefaultHttpClient mClient = new DefaultHttpClient(defHttpParams);
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(mServerUrl);

postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity( [...some nameValuePairs] ));

try {
    ResponseHandler<String> httpResponceHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    responce = mClient.execute(postMethod, httpResponceHandler);
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    //...
}
```

(If I use local apache server, then everything works fine, but on phpnet.us I get exception.)

What should I do to make Java code work?

Comment: I don't see any PHP code there. Do you? Or you are just in a big confusion?

Comment: @yes123 - php doesnt matter, for example now it is "<?php 
echo "<code>0</code>"; ?>"

Comment: @Yoric: it wasn't me that added PHP as tag in this question

Comment: @yes123 - oh excuse me, there is some php file on server, but obviously the problem is not in it.

Comment: You are not using the same URL in both cases (one ist with `index.php`, the other one `without`. Try changing one or both of them.

Comment: @paulo i've tried. this doesnt work

Comment: If you could post a complete example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), we would have a chance to try it ourself and spot the problem.

Comment: Capture a wire trace (or set the apache debug appropriately). Perhaps there is a header difference of some note. At any rate it would be informative.

Comment: @paulo here is example:    http://gametest.phpnet.us/misc/TestForStackOverflow.zip

Comment: @MJB i cannot set apache debug because it is not my hosting. will try to capture a wire trace, thanx for advice.

Comment: Yorick - at worst you could send everything through an Http proxy you create....But wireshark would be faster if feasible. Besides, can't you run this code from your box and just see if the same error occurs?

Comment: @MJB "run this code from your box" - do you mean run apache on localhost with the same php files and make request to localhost? i've tried, it works fine.

Comment: @MJB amazing... if i set header: "postMethod.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)");" then everything works fine. thank you, you were right. it is a header difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

```
  // Create client with settings
  final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
  webClient.setTimeout(5000);

  // Create web request
  WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(new URL("http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss"), HttpMethod.POST);

  // Set the request parameters
  requestSettings.setRequestParameters(new ArrayList());
  requestSettings.getRequestParameters().add(new NameValuePair("field-keywords", "Doctor Who"));

  Page page = webClient.getPage(requestSettings);
  page.getWebResponse().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: wow, that works. but as i can see, htmlunit uses same libraries as code above. i need to clear up.

Comment: That's right, htmlunit does use apache httpcomponents which is what you used above. I find working with htmlunit easier and it does support javascript as well.

Comment: the difference is in header: "postMethod.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)");" so i actually dont need htmlunit. thank you anyway, your advice works too.